# swift - UIAlertController takes the user back to the first ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I use UIAlertController in my app and whenever the user clicks OK, it takes the user back to the first viewcontroller.

```
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func displayAlert(title:String, error: String){
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I use the function above to show the alert at any point on the viewcontroller.

What does that happen? How can I keep the user on the current viewcontroller?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Can you provide more code from you view controller? Specifically, how do you call `-displayAlert`?

Comment: can you please tell that your viewcontrollers are part of navigation controller or tabbar controller?

Comment: Your action dismisses the current view controller (not the alert). Is this what you want?

Comment: thanks guys for the comments, Arun - I have navigation controller only in some viewcontrollers but the alert i am testing doesnt have any connection to a viewcontroller including nav controller. - mbm, i have 6 viewcontrollers and 5 of them are have a navigation controller on them but the one i test doesnt have navigation controller. how can i troubleshoot if this is related to nav controller?

Comment: paul - i want to keep the user on the same viewcontroller after the user taps OK. is dissmissviewcontroller actually sends the user out of the viewcontroller?

Comment: paul - i removed the dismissviewcontroller and it stays on the same viewcontroller now :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action you are calling `self.dismissViewController` - in this context "self" is the current view controller, not your alert view, so you are actually requesting the removal of the current view controller.